# Linked list remove and return first element

Tags: c, list, loops, linked-list, element

I'm trying to parse commands in a shell script using C. I currently have the linked list set up but I'm having trouble removing and returning the first element properly. When I try to get the first element, it works fine once but then after that it gets stuck and goes into an infinite loop and I don't understand why. Thanks in advance for any help. Here's my code:

```
     enum command_type
       {
         AND_COMMAND,         // A && B
         SEQUENCE_COMMAND,    // A ; B
         OR_COMMAND,          // A || B
         PIPE_COMMAND,        // A | B
         SIMPLE_COMMAND,      // a simple command
         SUBSHELL_COMMAND,    // ( A )
       };

     // Data associated with a command.
     struct command
     {
       enum command_type type;

       // Exit status, or -1 if not known (e.g., because it has not exited yet).
       int status;

       // I/O redirections, or null if none.
       char *input;
       char *output;

       union
       {
         // for AND_COMMAND, SEQUENCE_COMMAND, OR_COMMAND, PIPE_COMMAND:
                  struct command *command[2];

         // for SIMPLE_COMMAND:
         char **word;

         // for SUBSHELL_COMMAND:
         struct command *subshell_command;
       } u;
     };

     typedef struct command_stream *command_stream_t;
     typedef struct command *command_t;

     struct command_stream
     {
        command_t command_stream;
        command_stream_t next;
     }

     command_t
     read_command_stream(command_stream_t s)
     {
        if(s)
        {
           command_t comm = s->command;
           s=s->next;
           return comm;
        }
        return NULL;
     }

     void printList(command_stream_t head)
     { 
        command_t command;
        while((command = read_command_stream(head)))
        { 
           //print_command is a function that takes in a command_t and then prints the    
           //command in a nice format.
           print_command(head->command);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Is it necessary for you to reinvent linked lists? Otherwise I suggest linking against a [library](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.33/glib-Singly-Linked-Lists.html) which provides that container. For me it looks like you are not traversing the list in your loop, head stays unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

In this function, you are modifying a *local copy* of the pointer (not the main pointer you are passing in), as a result your `head` pointer never moves.

```
 command_t
 read_command_stream(command_stream_t s)
 {
    if(s)
    {
       command_t comm = s->command;
       s=s->next;
       return comm;
    }
    return NULL;
 }
```

You need to change this function to accept a *pointer-to-pointer*, if you don't understand this concept, I suggest a good book (or a tutorial) will get you started.